# Test class for mass upload

Tags: apex

Hello someone please help on this test class of mass upload thing.I am unable to find any solution for this.

```
public class MassUpload{
transient public Blob M_Body{get;set;}
public String emailToalert{get;set;}
public String retURL{get;set;}


public MassUpload(){
emailToalert='';
retURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
}
public void massUpload(){
    if(M_Body==null || M_Body.size()==0){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select a file to attach.'));
            return;
    }
    try{
    List<String> csvFileLines=M_Body.toString().split('\n');
    csvFileLines.remove(0);
    if(csvFileLines!=null && csvFileLines.size()>0){
         MassUpload mass=new MassUpload(csvFileLines,emailToalert);
         Database.executeBatch(mass,26);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct');
        ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what you have written so far for this?

Comment: Hello Himansu,i have not write anything for this. i am unable to understand what is " transient public Blob " and how to implement this.its work is to upload large amount of records in a custom object.i wrote test classes for different type of controller.but this is totally new to me.so i want help on this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are confused about the [**transient variable**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) it would have been better that you read about it. anyways.

If you have basic understanding of test class you will get your starting pointer from this code.

1. You have a blog variable inside your class so you need some blog data to test your class here is the way you can create blob data

   ```
   Blob b = Blob.valueOf('Test Data\n New Test Data \n');
   ```
2. Create a object of your apex class and pass null value to your controller.

   ```
   //negetive test case by passing blob as null
   Test.Starttest();
   MassUpload m = new MassUpload();
   m.Blob M_Body=null;
   Test.Stoptest();
   ```
3. Create a object of your apex class and pass this value to your controller.

   ```
   //positive test case by passing blob as value created in step 1
   Test.Starttest();
   MassUpload m = new MassUpload();
   m.Blob M_Body=b;
   Test.Stoptest();
   ```

Try to work with this code and creating different test methods and let us know your issues and progress. I am not pasting whole code here because this support forum is all about getting help what you have done already not passing your work to community members. I hope you will understand it :)